# Converting NSDictionary to Json String causes re-ordering of elements

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I am trying to convert an NSDictionary object to a json string using the following:

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options :[])
var string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
```

However it re-orders the individual elements alphabetically, this is what Swift returns:

```
{"client-nonce":"4q7581q6CbkAlJAAajHuWFiLJTPKJLpk","timestamp":"1480560235","token":"5aeba5cb66644e8e739765632a23f2f98a4035f99306f46777c67cea652dad79","url":"http://api.uselinkthrow.local/api/me/stream/friend/links"}
```

I would like to keep the order in which the dictionary was made, thus returning this:

```
{"token":"5aeba5cb66644e8e739765632a23f2f98a4035f99306f46777c67cea652dad79","timestamp":"1480560235","client-nonce":"4q7581q6CbkAlJAAajHuWFiLJTPKJLpk","url":"http://api.uselinkthrow.local/api/me/stream/friend/links"}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: That's how the world works.  Besides, what are implications if dictionary keys are not in order?

Comment: HMAC hashes will differ

Comment: "Does anyone know how I can do this?"  WHY do you want to do this?  If you can explain why, then people may be able to offer sensible solutions.  If you really want to do this, then a dictionary (alone) is the wrong data structure.  You would need either an array, or a combination of an array and a dictionary.  Dictionaries are unordered by nature.  Arrays are ordered.  This applies in JSON as well as in swift.  However, depending on your answer to the "WHY?" question, you may be better off continuing to use a dictionary, and then manipulating its keys into some order when required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.

JSON Object is a key-value pair, there is no order, and you can't order it and last the order won't matter

For more detail check [json.org](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Yeh I figured this but didn't know if I could override this, I'll have to deal with this server side. Thanks

Comment: What we did to solve the problem is to compute the hash on the sorted keys and their values before converting the dictionary to JSON. It's not an ideal solution, but as long as the server and client algorithms match the hashes will.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think the only way is to construct the JSON String by yourself rather than relying on JSONSerialization. Because in the end the data you will send to the server side will be in String format.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with just a dictionary and just flat (single-level) JSON.

Dictionaries are un-ordered by nature, both in JSON and in Swift (and any other language).  If you need to maintain an order, you should use an array.

It's difficult to give a specific answer to your question, because you haven't provided any reasons why you want to maintain this order, nor details on the nature of how the data is generated (eg, will the dictionary always have the same keys, and should they always be in the same order?).

However, if it really is necessary to maintain order AND if you are in a position to use a different JSON format, you could do it by either of the following two methods, depending on your requirements:

1. If the keys are always going to be the same and in the same order...

Populate your JSON from an array and not from your original dictionary.  Since you know what order the elements are in, you know which element is which without needing to have any keys.

2. If the keys are not always going to be the same, OR are not always going to be in the same order...

Maintain an array of ordered keys separately, as well as the dictionary, and then use the array to access the dictionary values in the same order that the keys are stored within the array.

Depending on your requirements, you may need to have the array also stored in the JSON (eg, combined with your dictionary into a parent dictionary).

This is probably a bit kludgy, but to get a better answer, you may have to provide more information on what your requirements actually are.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, it's a dictionary, it's not designed to provide ordered keys.  It is designed to have quick hash lookup, so just go ahead and use that to put things in the right order.

I'm not sure of **why** you want some kind of ordered string, so this is just an example for you to work off of to print strings in the order you want:

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] {
    ["token", "timestamp", "client-nonce", "url"].forEach({ print(String(describing: json?[$0])) })
}
```